# If statement in a Loop

Tags: matlab

I want my code to check if my 'e' components are in range of +,- 0.72 to +,- 0.73 to store the magnitude of Delta_theta and M in a vector for Plot. But I don't really know what is wrong in the last if statement. I just tried to store the amount of M that satisfies this condition in another matrix 'G' and plot it against delta theta, but it doesn't work either.
With kind regards.

I am sure the second and all other statements are correct, I just need help for the last one, thanks
Problem is Here

```
    if e(Idx_1,Idx_2) >=0.072 && e(Idx_1,Idx_2) < 0.077 || e(Idx_1,Idx_2) <=-0.072 && e(Idx_1,Idx_2) > -0.077;
   G=M;
   end
```

```
clear all
clc
%% Constants
B=1.2;
H=0.35;
R=2.93;
b=1;
h=0.24;
d_c=0.06;
D_s=0.03;
d_s=0.4;
r_s=0.015;
N_s=2;
E_s=200e9;
f_y=500e6;
E_c=43.6e9;
v_c=0.24;
f_c=35.5e6;
F=1.9;
A_s=pi*r_s^2;
e=0.3*h;
%% Operator
Idx_1 = 0;
for delta_theta =-40*10^-3:0.05*10^-3:40*10^-3
    alpha_e=0;
    alpha_p=0;
    beta_e=0;
    beta_p=0;
    r_b=0;
    r_s=0;
    r_e=0;
    Idx_1 = Idx_1 + 1;
    Idx_2 = 0;
    delta_thetavalue(Idx_1)=delta_theta;
    A=r_s-(f_y*d_s/(E_s*delta_theta));
   for delta_l=-10*10^-2:0.05*10^-2:10*10^-2
        Idx_2 = Idx_2 + 1;
        delta_lvalue(Idx_2)=delta_l;
        r_0=R-(delta_l/delta_theta);
        r_1=R-((1/delta_theta)*(delta_l+(F*f_c*d_c)/E_c));
        if delta_theta >=0
                r_op=R+(h/2);
                r_cl=R-(h/2);
                if r_0 >= r_op && r_1<=r_cl
                    alpha_e=1;
                    r_b=r_op;
                    r_e=r_cl;
                elseif r_0 >=r_op && r_cl<r_1 && r_1<r_op
                    alpha_e=1;
                    alpha_p=1;
                    r_b=r_op;
                    r_e=r_1;
                elseif r_0 >=r_op && r_1>=r_op
                    alpha_p=1;
                    r_b=r_op;
                    r_e=r_op;
                elseif r_s<r_0 && r_0<r_op && r_1<=r_cl
                    alpha_e=1;
                    r_b=r_0;
                    r_e=r_cl;
                elseif r_s<r_0 && r_0<r_op && r_1>r_cl
                    alpha_e=1;
                    alpha_p=1;
                    r_b=r_0;
                    r_e=r_1;
                elseif A<r_0 && r_cl<r_0 && r_0<=r_s && r_1<=r_cl
                     alpha_e=1;
                     beta_e=1;
                     r_b=r_0;
                     r_e=r_cl;
                elseif A<r_0 && r_cl<r_0 && r_0<=r_s && r_1>r_cl
                     alpha_e=1;
                     alpha_p=1;
                     beta_e=1;
                     r_b=r_0;
                     r_e=r_1;
                elseif A>=r_0 && r_0>r_cl && r_1<=r_cl
                     alpha_e=1;
                     beta_p=1;
                     r_b=r_0;
                     r_e=r_cl;
                elseif A>=r_0 && r_0>r_cl && r_1>r_cl
                     alpha_e=1;
                     alpha_p=1;
                     beta_p=1;
                     r_b=r_0;
                     r_e=r_1;
                elseif r_0 <= r_cl
                    r_b=r_cl;
                    r_e=r_cl;
                
                end
                
                 
        else
          r_op=R-(h/2);
          r_cl=R+(h/2);
                if r_0 <= r_op && r_1 >= r_cl
                    alpha_e=1;
                    r_b=r_op;
                    r_e=r_cl;
                elseif r_0 <=r_op && r_1>r_op && r_cl>r_1
                    alpha_e=1;
                    alpha_p=1;
                    r_b=r_op;
                    r_e=r_1;
                elseif r_0 <=r_op && r_1<=r_op
                    alpha_p=1;
                    r_b=r_op;
                    r_e=r_op;
                elseif r_s>r_0 && r_0>r_op && r_1>=r_cl
                    alpha_e=1;
                    r_b=r_0;
                    r_e=r_cl;
                elseif r_s>r_0 && r_0>r_op && r_1<r_cl
                    alpha_e=1;
                    alpha_p=1;
                    r_b=r_0;
                    r_e=r_1;
                elseif A>r_0 && r_cl>r_0 && r_0>=r_s && r_1>=r_cl
                     alpha_e=1;
                     beta_e=1;
                     r_b=r_0;
                     r_e=r_cl;
                elseif A>r_0 && r_cl>r_0 && r_0>=r_s && r_1<r_cl
                     alpha_e=1;
                     alpha_p=1;
                     beta_e=1;
                     r_b=r_0;
                     r_e=r_1;
                elseif A<=r_0 && r_0<r_cl && r_1>r_cl
                     alpha_e=1;
                     beta_p=1;
                     r_b=r_0;
                     r_e=r_cl;
                elseif A<=r_0 && r_0<r_cl && r_1<=r_cl
                     alpha_e=1;
                     alpha_p=1;
                     beta_p=1;
                     r_b=r_0;
                     r_e=r_1;
                elseif r_0 >= r_cl
                    r_b=r_cl;
                    r_e=r_cl;
                end
                
        end
            M(Idx_1,Idx_2)=alpha_e*(E_c*b/d_c)*((delta_l/2)*((r_b-R)^2-(r_e-R)^2)+(delta_theta/3)*((r_b-R)^3-(r_e-R)^3))+alpha_p*(-F*f_c*b*abs(r_cl-r_e)*(((r_cl+r_e)/2)-R))+beta_e*E_s*A_s*((delta_l/d_s)+(delta_theta/d_s)*(r_s-R))*(r_s-R)+beta_p*f_y*A_s*(r_s-R);
            N(Idx_1,Idx_2)=alpha_e*(E_c*b/d_c)*(delta_l*(r_e-r_b)+(delta_theta/2)*((r_e-R)^2-(r_b-R)^2))+alpha_p*(-F*f_c*b*abs(r_cl-r_e))+beta_e*E_s*A_s*((delta_l/d_s)+(delta_theta/d_s)*(r_s-R))+beta_p*f_y*A_s;
        
            e=M./N;

            
                
            


   end
   if e(Idx_1,Idx_2) >=0.072 && e(Idx_1,Idx_2) < 0.077 || e(Idx_1,Idx_2) <=-0.072 && e(Idx_1,Idx_2) > -0.077;
   G=M;
   end
    
end 

plot(delta_thetavalue,G)
```

Comment: you have a lot of conditions in the `elseif`. Are you sure one of them will always be satisfied? what if at some point none of them are?

Comment: Also, plrease provide a [mcve], i.e. please shorten your code by a lot

Comment: @AnderBiguri they are all disjoint. Without them, no one could evaluate the code. And I wrote what I did and what I want and where I think the problem is "in the last if statement". I tried to be clear. There is no need to check the second loop for correctness. 
Thanks

Comment: Please do remove all that is not required from the code here, otherwise its hard to help

Comment: No, it is not more clear now, sorry. You *think* the issue is in that one line, but we don’t know for sure, it could be elsewhere too. Looking at that one bit of code only doesn’t make your problem clear. And looking at the large program is waaaay too much work for anyone to want to do for free. So what you need to do is shorten your program, simplifying it to the bare minimum to illustrate your problem. Then we have something to discuss here.

Comment: I did want to help. It is unfortunate that you interpreted my attempt at helping as an annoyance. Creating a minimal reproducible example is a really good skill to have, that will help you solve many types of problems. It is the way you can isolate where the problem happens, in cases like these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  solved this problem like this :

```
t=0;
for Idx_1=1:1601 ;
    for Idx_2=1:401;
        if (e(Idx_1,Idx_2) >=0.072 && e(Idx_1,Idx_2) < 0.073) || (e(Idx_1,Idx_2) <=-0.072 && e(Idx_1,Idx_2) > -0.073);
           t=t+1;     
           dt(t)=delta_thetavalue(Idx_1);
           mf(t)=M(Idx_1,Idx_2);
        end
    end
end  
plot(dt,mf)
```

Answer (score 1):

We cannot check how your function `e` works but have you tried wrapping your conditions in parenthesis so it understand that it need to check them in pair?

```
if (e(Idx_1,Idx_2) >=0.072 && e(Idx_1,Idx_2) < 0.077) || (e(Idx_1,Idx_2) <=-0.072 && e(Idx_1,Idx_2) > -0.077);
```

also it could be easier to debug if you evaluate it once

```
evaluation = e(Idx_1,Idx_2); // you can print or anything to check the value before the if expression

if (evaluation >=0.072 && evaluation < 0.077) || (evaluation <=-0.072 && evaluation > -0.077);
```

Comment: I have tried but still not. Delta _ l and Delta_ Theta are my input values M and N are general formula equal to some number among these 20 if stamens. these instructions are in a paper so they are correct and I checked the correctness. e is each element of M divided by each element of N now I need to store each element of e in this range to a vector or matrix and plot them against Delta Theta at the end I need ( Delta Theta , ,- 0.072<= e elements +- < 0.077

Comment: M and N are general formula equal to some number. So is M a number or a vector?

Comment: M is a Matrix in my case but physically is a number

Comment: Thanks everyone, I understood that the problem of the code is not in this if statement, I will check the rest again.

Answer (score 0):

Since you specifically ask for help for the last if statement, I can tell you there is nothing wrong with it. It appears your "e" function might have some bugs. Here is a dummy code snippet for you to play with the eVal which is a placeholder for your e(arg1, arg2) function. You should narrow this down and make sure where the error is by using the built in debugger.

```
clc;
eVal = 0.076;
G    = zeros(3);
M    = eye(3);

if eVal >= 0.072 && eVal < 0.077 || eVal <= -0.072 && eVal > -0.077;
 G = M;
end

disp(G); % Should return eye(3) if the statement is true
```

Comment: but if you run the whole code, you will see that there are some numbers in e in this range, but G is still empty